# PHP Display HTML retrieved from database

Tags: php, html

I'm retrieving some html source code that is stored in a database and storing that in a PHP variable. The html source code is the rows for a table and might look like this:

```
<tr><td>10:00 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:15 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:30 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr>
```

I'm storing this in a variable $tableRows.

In my PHP page I have some of the table code in the page and I'm attempting to include the table rows like this:

```
<table class="table table-condensed table-hover table-bordered">

<tr>
<th scope="col">Time</th>
<th scope="col"><?php  echo $date ; ?></th>
</tr>

<?php

echo $tableRows ;

?>          
</table>
```

In the browser I'm seeing the html source, e.g. I see:

```
<tr><td>10:00 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:15 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:30 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr>
```

instead of the rendered table? I've tried htmlentities but that's not working either.

Comment: whats the output of print_r($tableRows)?

Comment: I see the html source code in the browser, e.g.: <tr><td>10:00 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr>

Comment: go and look for your pages resulting html source, maybe you find the same lines which @Axel Grazx posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummmmm.... Maybe your `$tableRows` variable has the HTML encoded, like this:

```
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;10:00 AM&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;success&quot;&gt;Available&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt; 
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;10:15 AM&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;success&quot;&gt;Available&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt; 
&lt;tr&gt;&lt;td&gt;10:30 AM&lt;/td&gt;&lt;td class=&quot;success&quot;&gt;Available&lt;/td&gt;&lt;/tr&gt;
```

In that case:

```
...
</tr>

<?php

echo html_entity_decode($tableRows);

?>          
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks - using echo html_entity_decode($tableRows); works - I don't believe the HTML is encoded but it's working great now.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
<?php
$a='
<tr><td>10:00 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:15 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> 
<tr><td>10:30 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr>'; 



echo '
<tr>
<th scope="col">Time</th>
<th scope="col"><?php  echo $date ; ?></th>
</tr>'.$a;
```

[DEMO](http://3v4l.org/4DNEV)

Answer (score 0):

This is giving me proper output you can try that

```
<?php
$tableRows='<tr><td>10:00 AM</td><td class="success">Available</td></tr> ';
echo $tableRows;
?>
```

Comment: this is not what OP asked.